# Can't not get my app running on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have my app running successfully on my local machine.
But when I tried to push it to heroku and get it running live on internet, it fails with this error message.

```
git push heroku mybranch:master

....
   undefined method `admin_notes=' for #<ActiveAdmin::Application:0x007fb896f03678>
   /tmp/build_fad3ae53-5d67-4131-93b9-c46de602ed36/config/initializers/active_admin.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_fad3ae53-5d67-4131-93b9-c46de602ed36/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activeadmin-0.6.2/lib/active_admin.rb:66:in `setup'
   /tmp/build_fad3ae53-5d67-4131-93b9-c46de602ed36/config/initializers/active_admin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_fad3ae53-5d67-4131-93b9-c46de602ed36/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
   /tmp/build_fad3ae53-5d67-4131-93b9-c46de602ed36/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
   /tmp/build_fad3ae53-5d67-4131-93b9-c46de602ed36/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
   /tmp/build_fad3ae53-5d67-4131-93b9-c46de602ed36/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
   /tmp/build_fad3ae53-5d67-4131-93b9-c46de602ed36/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
   /tmp/build_fad3ae53-5d67-4131-93b9-c46de602ed36/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/engine.rb:592:in `each'
   /tmp/build_fad3ae53-5d67-4131-93b9-c46de602ed36/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/engine.rb:592:in `block in <class:Engine>'
   /tmp/build_fad3ae53-5d67-4131-93b9-c46de602ed36/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
   /tmp/build_fad3ae53-5d67-4131-93b9-c46de602ed36/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
   /tmp/build_fad3ae53-5d67-4131-93b9-c46de602ed36/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
   /tmp/build_fad3ae53-5d67-4131-93b9-c46de602ed36/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
   /tmp/build_fad3ae53-5d67-4131-93b9-c46de602ed36/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
   /tmp/build_fad3ae53-5d67-4131-93b9-c46de602ed36/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
   /tmp/build_fad3ae53-5d67-4131-93b9-c46de602ed36/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
   /tmp/build_fad3ae53-5d67-4131-93b9-c46de602ed36/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_fad3ae53-5d67-4131-93b9-c46de602ed36/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
   /tmp/build_fad3ae53-5d67-4131-93b9-c46de602ed36/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
   /tmp/build_fad3ae53-5d67-4131-93b9-c46de602ed36/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
   /tmp/build_fad3ae53-5d67-4131-93b9-c46de602ed36/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
   /tmp/build_fad3ae53-5d67-4131-93b9-c46de602ed36/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
   /tmp/build_fad3ae53-5d67-4131-93b9-c46de602ed36/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/application.rb:305:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
   /tmp/build_fad3ae53-5d67-4131-93b9-c46de602ed36/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:93:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_fad3ae53-5d67-4131-93b9-c46de602ed36/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_fad3ae53-5d67-4131-93b9-c46de602ed36/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:23:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
   /tmp/build_fad3ae53-5d67-4131-93b9-c46de602ed36/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
   Tasks: TOP => environment
   (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here is my gem file and active_admin.rb file which I think errors are coming from.

Gemfile
    source 'http://rubygems.org'
    ruby '2.0.0'

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.14'
gem 'json'
gem 'thin'
gem 'rails_12factor'
gem 'paymill'
gem 'pg'
gem 'haml'
gem 'jammit', :git => 'https://github.com/documentcloud/jammit.git', :branch => 'master'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'friendly_id'
gem 'devise', '~> 2.2.7'
gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'formtastic'
gem 'inherited_resources'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 2.4'
gem 'country_select'
gem 'coffee-script'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'escape_utils'
  gem 'rails-footnotes'
  gem 'rack-webconsole'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pry-debugger'
  # gem 'taps'
  # gem 'steak'
  # gem 'spork'
end

group :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.1.0'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.14.0'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '~> 1.4.0', require: false
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.0.1'
  # gem 'capybara', '~> 2.1.0'
  gem 'simplecov', require: false
end
```

config/initializers/active_admin.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|

# == Site Title
#
# Set the title that is displayed on the main layout
# for each of the active admin pages.
#
config.site_title = "IncomeHawk"


# == Default Namespace
#
# Set the default namespace each administration resource
# will be added to.
#
# eg:
#   config.default_namespace = :hello_world
#
# This will create resources in the HelloWorld module and
# will namespace routes to /hello_world/*
#
# To set no namespace by default, use:
#   config.default_namespace = false
# config.default_namespace = :admin


# == User Authentication
#
# Active Admin will automatically call an authentication
# method in a before filter of all controller actions to
# ensure that there is a currently logged in admin user.
#
# This setting changes the method which Active Admin calls
# within the controller.
config.authentication_method = :http_authenticate


# == Current User
#
# Active Admin will associate actions with the current
# user performing them.
#
# This setting changes the method which Active Admin calls
# to return the currently logged in user.
config.current_user_method = false #:current_user


# == Admin Notes
#
# Admin notes allow you to add notes to any model
#
# Admin notes are enabled by default, but can be disabled
# by uncommenting this line:
#
config.admin_notes = true


# == Controller Filters
#
# You can add before, after and around filters to all of your
# Active Admin resources from here.
#
# config.before_filter :do_something_awesome


# == Register Stylesheets & Javascripts
#
# We recomend using the built in Active Admin layout and loading
# up your own stylesheets / javascripts to customize the look
# and feel.
#
# To load a stylesheet:
#   config.register_stylesheet 'my_stylesheet.css'
#
# To load a javascript file:
#   config.register_javascript 'my_javascript.js'
```

end

Comment: have you migrated the Database ?

Comment: Did you code work locally?

Comment: No. I didn't migrate the Database. that could be the reason?

Comment: Code works fine locally.

Comment: `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: heroku run rake db:migrate   doesn't work and gives me the same error like I described above.

Comment: Try to add a production group in your gemfile with gem 'rails_12factor' gem 'pg'.